# My Favourite Tags have no questions which need answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

My Favourite Tags apparently have no questions which need answers, even though I'm selecting *any*.

[image: That's a miss!]

I'm not sure if this is due to the wildcard tags or if the *any* toggle doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you use wildcard tag filters. We don't support that at the moment.

Comment: Might want to mention that in the main topic. I just created [another post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256830/wildcard-tags-should-show-all-pulled-tags-and-not-just-the-main-one) about wildcard tags.