# Wildcard tags should show all pulled tags and not just the main one

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, new-nav

In this case I'm filtering by the tag [tag:css*], but it's showing this as [css*] and showing the [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag's exerpt.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Oh. From [My Favourite Tags have no questions which need answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256827/my-favourite-tags-have-no-questions-which-need-answers):

> It's because you use wildcard tag filters. We don't support that at the moment.
>
> – [Sklivvz♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256829/211113)

Answer (score 2):

Sort of. We are not really keen to encourage wildcard tags for now, so I'm removing them from the list shown.

Comment: So what are we supposed to do? Add hundreds of tags to favorites? I can handle adding all `c#-*` and `*xaml*` tags and keep the list up to date, I guess, but those who want `*sql*` will be disappointed. And I certainly prefer having clean favorite tags list.