# The "favorite tags" filter doesn’t include all my favorite tags

Tags: support, tag-watching, new-nav

I have more than 50 favorite tags on Stack Overflow.

But when I select the "favorite tags" filter in the new navigation, it only lists 6 tags.

Why’s that? And how can I include *all* my favorite tags?

([FWIW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256827/193139), none of my favorite tags contain a wildcard.)

Comment: (Btw., I have the same problem here on Meta SE: I have 11 favorite tags, but the filter only shows 1.)

Comment: yeah, that's not going to happen. It's too onerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s working now (don’t know since when): all my favorite tags are included (on Stack Overflow as well as here on Meta).